# Categorical Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dataset=['apple','orange','banana','grape','orange','apple','kiwi','apple']
```

So the feature type of the data set is category but how should I code to identify the feature values in the data set?

Command:
print('The feature values of the dataset:',*what should I type here?*)

Output: The feature values of the dataset: 'apple','orange','banana','grape','kiwi'

Comment: print(list(set(dataset)))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use a python set

```
dataset={'apple','orange','banana','grape','orange','apple','kiwi','apple'}
```

Sets enforce that the values are unique. If you want to maintain the original list, you can convert it to a set as

```
data = ['apple','orange','banana','grape','orange','apple','kiwi','apple']
dataset = set(data)
print(dataset)
#returns {'banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'orange'}
```